# react-native: android: exitApp leaves process alive

Tags: android, react-native

I've tried several different combinations of `BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {})` to exit the app on Android but in all cases, the process is left alive. Returning `true`, `false` or calling `BackHandler.exitApp()` doesn't behave any differently either.

Does anyone know how to kill the process without having to write a bridge call to a native function that may run `System.exit(0)`?

Comment: Why do you want to kill the process?

Comment: It turns out Android users expect apps to close upon hitting the back button. I'm an iOS user and this request came from one of my users.

Comment: Google has put a lot of effort into convincing users who think this way that they're wrong. As long as your activity isn't leaving any background threads running, there's nothing wrong with the process being alive. In fact, it's better for battery life if the framework doesn't have to reload it the next time it's needed.

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/TBuJVev9V5k/ECXrVT8NF5IJ

Comment: Thanks for this info Kevin. I guess my understanding was clearly incorrect.